# Fit table size with the page size in latex

Tags: latex, tabular

I have many tables with different numbers of columns that should fit with the page size. For that, I used codes similar to the one below:

```
\begin{table}
    \caption{Values}
    \centering
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
        \begin{tabular}{!{\vrule}l!{\vrule}l!{\vrule}l!{\vrule}l!{\vrule}l!{\vrule}l} 
            \toprule
            DS             & Criterion1 & Criterion2 & Criterion3 & Criterion4  \\ 
            \midrule
            DS1 & V1 & V2 & V3  & V4 \\ 
            \midrule
            DS2       & V5 & V6 & V7 & V8 \\ 
            \midrule
            DS3       & V9 & V10 & V11 & V12 \\ 
            \midrule
            DS4 & V13 & V14 & V15 & V16 \\
            \botrule
        \end{tabular}
    }
\end{table}
```

This code generates the tables but shows errors of the kind: **Illegal characters in array arg**.
I didn't understand this error.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `\resizebox` for elements which contain text, choose an appropriate font size instead. This will give better typographical results.

Comment: ... that being said, please make a [mre] which allows us to reproduce the error

Comment: ... and please read the `booktabs` user guide how to design better looking tables by removing vertical lines

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz. Thank you for replying. However, the font size doesn't matter for my context, I have other tables that have more than 15 columns which must reduce the size so as not to exceed the page width. Is there any other way to create such tables without ```\resizebox```? Thanks again

Comment: The fontsize DOES matter. If you use a smaller font size instead of scaling things down, good fonts will use slightly different shapes for the letters which are easier to read at small sizes. For example compare the shape of Q in `\tiny` and `\Huge` https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCBjZ.png The proportionably thicker strokes make it easier to read at small sizes

Comment: You can manually choose an appropriate font size with which your table fits on your page, or you can use the `fitting` library from tcolorbox to do this automatically, see https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1912#a2150 for an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion to edit your code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{table}
  \caption{Values}
  \label{tab:n}
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{5}{X}}
    \toprule
    DS  & Criterion1 & Criterion2 & Criterion3 & Criterion4 \\ 
    \midrule
    DS1 & V1         & V2         & V3         & V4 \\ 
    \midrule
    DS2 & V5         & V6         & V7         & V8 \\ 
    \midrule
    DS3 & V9         & V10        & V11        & V12 \\ 
    \midrule
    DS4 & V13        & V14        & V15        & V16 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of output]

1. Not related, but you should have a command `\label{...}` [after](https://www.stefaanlippens.net/latexcaptionlabel/) or in your `\caption{...}`.
2. Do not mix vertical lines (best of all avoid them) with the horizontal ones from the package `booktabs` (`toprule`, `midrule`, `bottomrule`).
3. And this should hopefully answer your question: try column type `X` from the package [`tabularx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) to better stretch the width of columns (I guess you have tables with more columns than this one).

Comment: can I use `\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}`? I need the table to split in multiple pages but it also needs to fit horizontally

Comment: @netotz sorry, I never tried, I don't know.

Comment: I ended up reducing the font size with `\small`